# How to get the term $\hat c^\dagger \hat c +\frac12$ in the derivation of qubit transmons quantization?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information

I'm wondering about qubit transmon quantization derivation, which I found [here](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/transmon-physics.html):

My question is the following:

[image]

How can I get this term, while derivation?

I tried to do it by myself, but my result was without this term (only $\hat{c}^\dagger$ and $\hat c$). I have no idea how can I get it.

Comment: Hello! It is [preferable](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/) to type out screenshots; for formulae, one can use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: The harmonic oscillator is *always* quantized like that!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, for sure, for harmonic oscillator the derivation is absolutely clear, but here I have a question on how to correctly open the brackets of $(c+c^{\dagger})^2$

Comment: In leading order the transmon is a harmonic oscillator.

Comment: no doubts it is, but my question here is rather about equation derivation (exact detatils of it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $[\hat{c},\,\hat{c}^\dagger]=1$, the diagonal terms in $(\hat{c}+\hat{c}^\dagger)^2$ are$$\hat{c}\hat{c}^\dagger+\hat{c}^\dagger c=2\hat{c}^\dagger c+1=2\left(\hat{c}^\dagger c+\frac12\right).$$It all stems from that.

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you please show the exact matrix of c, for example, didn’t get it, unfortunately.

Comment: @Curious Do you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creation_and_annihilation_operators#Matrix_representation)?

Comment: Yes, if we look depper in the equation I've posted, we'll get the following part of equation:

\sqrt{\frac{E_j}{2E_c}}(-(c_dagger-c)^2+(c_dagger+c)^2), which is not the same as (c+c_dagger)^2

Comment: @Curious No, but subtracting $(c-c^\dagger)^2$ just doubles the cross terms.

Comment: ah, ok, it is clear now, thank you! but how do you open the brackets of $(c-c^{\dagger})^2$ (or $(c+c^{\dagger})^2$)? I tried to use the matrix form of these operators and opened the brackets by $(a+b)^2$ standard algebraic formula.

Comment: @Curious You want$$(a+b)^2=(a+b)(a+b)=a^2+ab+b^2+ba$$instead, so$$(c\pm c^\dagger)^2=(c\pm c^\dagger)(c\pm c^\dagger)=c^2\pm cc^\dagger\pm c^\dagger c+c^{\dagger2}=c^2+c^{\dagger2}\pm(cc^\dagger+c^\dagger c).$$

Comment: Yes, it is more or less clear, but why can we ignore square terms here and use only diagonal (which are $cc^{\dagger}+c^{\dagger}c$)?

Comment: @Curious "it is helpful to observe" three quantities are equal, from which it follows a multiple of $(\hat{c}-\hat{c}^\dagger)^2-(\hat{c}+\hat{c}^\dagger)^2$ comes up.

Comment: ah, yes, I forgot about it and lost my attention, so now I can say that the question is absolutely clear for me, thank you so much!! you're the best explanator!